# Meaning of “Bei dem, was grad los ist.”

Tags: meaning, phrase

What’s the meaning of the following sentence?

> Bei dem, was grad los ist.

I could not get it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to German Language. Thank your for your contribution. People appear to see issues in your question leading to a downvote and votes to close your question. To avoid this please consider to elaborate your question by an [edit] showing us your own research effort, and give us an idea in what context you heard that expression. As this expression is very common I believe this to be a question of general interest. Also see [help] and [this meta post](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-for-translations-or-about-differences)

Answer (score 7):

It's a very colloquial phrasing meaning

> With everything that's going on right now... [e.g. we really
>   don't need any more trouble]

*grad* = gerade, jetzt

*los ist* von los sein, passieren

Comment: Adding to this, the _dem_ comes from the _das_ that refers to what happens, except it's in the dative case. _das, was grad los ist_ -> _bei dem, was grad los ist_

Comment: @Stephie: I agree, edited the answer. Thanks